# WordPress plugin for subscribing to categories and receiving notifications per email

Tags: email, wordpress

I am searching for a WordPress plugin which gives the ability to subscribe to categories. The user should be able to choose multiple categories.

So if user is subscribed to category and if somebody is posting new post in this category then user should receive email notification about it.

Ideally plugin should work like "[Subscribe To Comments Reloaded](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/)".

Comment: I guess that the user should be able to choose multiple categories. Does it also have to have the option (checkbox) *Subscribe to all categories*? Please [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Newsletter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/), it is very well valued (4.8 out of 5 stars) on the official WordPress site. [Here](http://www.thenewsletterplugin.com/plugins/newsletter/newsletter-preferences) you can find the explanation of its newsletter's preferences options. It allows to create different 'channels' which the user can subscribe, and gives the possibility to send emails by category. There are different ways the users can choose and manage their subscriptions.